# Fix forEach loop in javascript code

Tags: javascript, hibernate, jsp, exception, foreach

I hope anyone can help me. I've searched and tried a view solutions but none of these solved my problem.

I want to use `forEach` in Javascript.

Controller:

```
 model.addAttribute("aqua", aquaDao.aquaLoad());
 mv.setViewName("aqua");
```

In the jsp-file in a select-statement the `forEach` works without any problems. 
But in function it does not work.

Function:

```
function aqua_select() {
    <c:forEach var="aqua" items="${aqua}" varStatus="status">
    var  sName = "<c:out value="${aqua.name}"/>";
    alert('Test' +sName);
    </c:forEach> }
```

Exception:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing
>   JSP page /WEB-INF/view/aqua.jsp at line 27
>
> ```
> 24:   function aqua_select(value) {
> 25:       //var values = [];
> 26:       <c:forEach var="aqua" items="${aqua}" varStatus="status">
> 27:       var  sName = "<c:out value="${aqua.name}"/>";
> 28:       </c:forEach>
> 29:       alert('Test' + sName);
> 30:   }
> ```
>
> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Even without the exception the code doesn't really make any sense. You're generating a JavaScript function that re-declares the same variable over and over again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The function is only for testing and will be extended later. But the alert should show the variable sName with the current value. Or maybe I am simply wrong?

Comment: Well your code looks different in the two places it appears in your question. The first one has an `alert()` *inside* the `<c:forEach>` but the second has the `alert()` *outside*. It should not matter to the JSP code of course; I can't see why you'd get a NumberFormatException from that code.

Comment: The `alert()` is only for testing, too. ;-) Important is, that the `<c:forEach>` works. Do you need any further informations?

Comment: Right, but that exception just doesn't make any sense. Have you tried simply `var sName = "${aqua.name}";`? Using `<c:out/>` won't really do you any good anyway.

Comment: I have tried it and the same exception occured: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"

Comment: OH wait - if `aqua` holds an array, then that won't work: it'd be like writing `aqua["name"]` in Java. That's why you get a NumberFormatException - it's telling you that it expects a number, but you're using "name" instead.

Comment: Thank you. Now, no exception appear, but the function does not work. Nothing happens. No `alert message` will be displayed.

Comment: Well to diagnose the *JavaScript* side of the problem you should look for errors in the browser console, and also use "View source" to see what the code looks like *after* JSP processing is finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
  <script>
    var sName = {
       <c:forEach var="aqua" items="${aqua}" varStatus="status">
            '${aqua.name}'${!status.last ? ',' : ''}
        </c:forEach>
    };
//print arrays using javascript
  </script>
```

You would have an output like this.

```
<script>
 var sName = {'aqua1','aqua2','aqua3'};
</script>
```

Or if you have another property assuming its a Number.

```
  <script>
    var sName = {
       <c:forEach var="aqua" items="${aqua}" varStatus="status">
            '${aqua.name}' : ${aqua.anotherNumberProperty} ${!status.last ? ',' : ''}
        </c:forEach>
    };


      //output
      //sName = {
      //  'aqua1' : 0,
      //  'aqua2' : 1,
      //  'aqua3' : 2
      // };
  </script>
```